# How to add public key and private key for Encryption and Decryption in ROKU

Tags: encryption, roku, brightscript

I use the **roRSA** for encryption and decryption. And analyze [roRSA](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/components/rorsa.md) sample for our code. I Add `RSA.SetPrivateKey("tmp:/privateKey.txt")` instead of `pkg:/privateKey.txt`. And that file also created in my application and this file available some text then only Its given invalid in output.

Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: I don't know that framework, but the thing about URI's is that the first part designates the *protocol* more than a specific location. In other words, what's found using a `tmp:` and `kpg:` may be *interpreted* differently. For instance, I could imagine that the file contains a *reference* to the key rather than the key itself.

Comment: @maartenbodewes Thank you For your Reply.

Answer (score 0):

tmp folder is created runtime, so better use

> pkg:/privateKey.txt

where pkg denoted the root directory of current application.

For example:

```
rsa.setPrivateKey("pkg:/images/privateKey.txt")
```

images is the folder which you have created inside your application and inside it

> privatekey.txt

,Now you can add you private key here .